# Internal style not working for my pdf

Tags: php, html, css, pdf

```
$pdf = new Pdf([

           // set to use core fonts only
           'mode' => Pdf::MODE_CORE,
           // A4 paper format
           'format' => Pdf::FORMAT_A4,
           // portrait orientation
           'orientation' => Pdf::ORIENT_PORTRAIT,
           // stream to browser inline
           'destination' => Pdf::DEST_BROWSER,
           // your html content input
           'content' => $content,
           // format content from your own css file if needed or use the
           // enhanced bootstrap css built by Krajee for mPDF formatting
           'cssFile' => '@vendor/kartik-v/yii2-mpdf/assets/kv-mpdf-bootstrap.min.css',
           // any css to be embedded if required
           'cssInline' => '.kv-heading-1{font-size:18mm}',
           // set mPDF properties on the fly
           'options' => ['title' => 'Title'],
           // call mPDF methods on the fly
           'methods' => [
              // 'SetHeader'=>['Krajee Report Header'],
              // 'SetFooter'=>['{PAGENO}'],
           ],
           'marginTop' => 1,
           'marginBottom' => 1,
           'marginLeft' => 2,
           'marginRight' => 0,

        ]);
```

Html:

```
$html = '<style>'. $mystyle .' </style>';

$html .= '<div>' . $mydiv . '</div>';

        echo $html;
```

Trying to print the div with the internal style but the internal style don't seem to work even though div is showing. There is not error shown so is there any chance that it doesn't support internal style? Or did i miss out something?

**Inline style is working

Answer (score 1):

The answer I found to the internal style not working is because whatever I pass  to the PDF is read as 'content'. I need to pass the style to 'cssInline' and not 'content'.

Comment: But anyway to pass 2 models at the same time? One for content and another for cssInline

Comment: Is this an answer? I don't think it is

Comment: @Martin Why not? I do explain why it doesn't work an how to make it work

Comment: I wasn't sure if it was an answer or a continuation of the question! Thanks for clarifying